# Can strong entity have foreign keys?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, entities

I want to identify this ER diagram's strong and weak entities. I doubt that can a strong entity have foreign keys. What are the strong entities and weak entities of this ER diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, a strong entity can not have a FK as it is independent of any other entity in the schema.

For example, a Booking is a weak entity and a Vehicle type is a strong entity.
There could be vehicles Types without any booking made.
But you can not have a booking without vehicle type, that makes the booking a weak entity.

The same happens with Vehicle and Vehicles Type